# twilio Say verb only after pressing a specific key

Tags: php, twilio

How do I use an alternative action in twilio? What I'm trying to do is to capture a specific key (*). If this key is pressed it will do another thing instead of the default one. Here's what I currently have:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
    <Gather finishOnKey="*" action="/another_thing" method="POST">
      <Say>Hi this is the initial message</Say>
    </Gather>

    <Say>Hi this is the default message. Please enter a 3 digit number</Say>
    <Gather numDigits="3" action="/save_number" method="POST" />
</Response>
```

So basically I want to submit to the `another_thing` route if the * key is pressed. But what's currently happening when I press the * key is that it goes to the say verb right below the gather. So it says `Hi this is the default message. Please enter a 3 digit number` instead of my expected which is it will go to the `another_thing` and output whatever it is that's in there.

Is this possible with twilio or am I doing something wrong? Please help. Thanks in advance!

If it helps here's what I have for the `another_path`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
   <Say>Hey whats up!</Say>
</Response>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Twilio Evangelist here.

So, you're on the right track. You need to use a separate TwiML route for the default message, and then everything should be okay. I would also suggest you use `numDigits` instead of `finishOnKey`. If you use `finishOnKey`, you're not actually sent that character. There is more info in the documentation for [`<Gather>`](https://www.twilio.com/docs/api/twiml/gather).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Gather numDigits="1" action="/another_thing" method="POST">
    <Say>Hi this is the initial message</Say>
  </Gather>
</Response>
```

This TwiML will run, and if the caller doesn't press a key, the `<Gather>` will time out (you can adjust the length of that with `timeout="3"` for example), but it will still make a request to `/another_thing`. Note that the timeout starts after the `<Say>` completes.

In your `/another_thing` route, you can examine the `Digits` parameter sent by Twilio, and decide what to do. If they didn't press a key:

```
<Response>
  <Say>Hi this is the default message. Please enter a 3 digit number</Say>
  <Gather numDigits="3" action="/save_number" method="POST" />
</Response>
```

Where as is they pressed the `*` key:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Response>
  <Say>Hey whats up!</Say>
</Response>
```

Hope this helps!